# Centos 7 VM won't boot, Kernel Panic, Google Compute Engine

Tags: centos, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Two weeks ago my Centos 7 VM that's been running on Google Compute Engine for two years suddenly crashed, serial console log reveals:

```
[    1.668426] List of all partitions:
[    1.669174] No filesystem could mount root, tried: 
[    1.669979] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    1.671773] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 #1
[    1.673630] Hardware name: Google Google Compute Engine/Google Compute Engine, BIOS Google 01/01/2011
[    1.675841] Call Trace:
[    1.676467]  [<ffffffffadb64147>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
[    1.677456]  [<ffffffffadb5d850>] panic+0xe8/0x21f
[    1.678455]  [<ffffffffae186761>] mount_block_root+0x291/0x2a0
[    1.679508]  [<ffffffffae1867c3>] mount_root+0x53/0x56
[    1.680619]  [<ffffffffae186902>] prepare_namespace+0x13c/0x174
[    1.681535]  [<ffffffffae1863df>] kernel_init_freeable+0x1f8/0x21f
[    1.684161]  [<ffffffffae185b1f>] ? initcall_blacklist+0xb0/0xb0
[    1.685266]  [<ffffffffadb52220>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    1.686058]  [<ffffffffadb5222e>] kernel_init+0xe/0x100
[    1.686884]  [<ffffffffadb76c37>] ret_from_fork_nospec_begin+0x21/0x21
[    1.688183]  [<ffffffffadb52220>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    1.690932] Kernel Offset: 0x2c400000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
```

I can mount the disk in another instance and read the data. It's only 70% full. Launching the disk in a larger instance produces the same result.

Any suggestions??? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I was using Centos 7.

I Found that my latest kernel installed crashed causing this.

I managed to login to it with old kernel.

to list the kernel:

`#rpm -q kernel`

To remove the latest kernel:

`#yum remove <kernel-3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64>` (replace with your latest kernel)

Rebooted machine, installed the new kernel again, all good.

========

AFASIK in our case when we did the latest yum update we lost network connectivity part way through and this caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occurd when your /boot partition is full or you are missing the initramfs for that kernel.

Option #1 Choose another kernel from the GRUB menu under Advanced options for Ubuntu and run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k version
```

This generates the initrd for version (replace version with the kernel version string such as 4.15.0-36-generic) then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Option #2 Choose another kernel from the GRUB menu under Advanced options for Ubuntu and  remove old linux kernels

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: What is all this stuff about Ubuntu? He is not using Ubuntu.

Comment: GRUB would be great, but i believe the GRUB menu is not accessible in Google Compute Engine-provided CentOS images.